# Adding sound effects to WPF Surface application

Tags: c#, wpf, audio, pixelsense

I am trying to play a sound whenever an object is touched/moved in my WPF Surface application, to depict it has been selected or its movement. Here is what I tried but it doesn't seem to work.

```
SoundPlayerAction soundPlayerAction = new SoundPlayerAction();
soundPlayerAction.Source = new Uri(@"C:\Resources\Selection.wav", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
EventTrigger eventTrigger = new EventTrigger(TouchEnterEvent); // this is the event you want to trigger the sound effect.
eventTrigger.Actions.Add(soundPlayerAction);
```

Any feedback or ideas will be much appreciated.

Comment: Sure that `C:\Resources` is the correct path?

Comment: Yes actually it's something like @"C:\Users\hci\Desktop\N\TTools\TTool\Resources\Selection.wav. It does seem to be correct as I have the audio file in this folder, I also added it in Visual Studio in the solution explorer.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new folder in your project and rename it to SOUNDS then insert your sound files in it and try this:

```
  SoundPlayerAction soundPlayerAction = new SoundPlayerAction();
    soundPlayerAction.Source = new Uri(@"SOUNDS\Selection.wav", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);


    EventTrigger eventTrigger = new EventTrigger(TouchEnterEvent); // this is the event you want to trigger the sound effect.

    eventTrigger.Actions.Add(soundPlayerAction);
     Triggers.Add(eventTrigger); // Add this event trigger to Window.Triggers collection.
```

Answer (score 0):

`C:\Resources\Selection.wav` is obviously not the correct path of the sound file.

You should create a folder named "Resources" in your Visual Studio project, and add the sound file to that folder. Then go to the properties of the sound file and set its `Build Action` to `Resource` and also set `Copy to Output Directory` to `Copy aways` or `Copy if newer`.

Now you can access the file by a relative Uri like this:

```
soundPlayerAction.Source = new Uri("Resources/Selection.wav", UriKind.Relative);
```

Comment: I tried this way and it still doesn't work. The sound doesn't play. I have a feeling maybe my event trigger is not appropriate? What I imagined it to do is whenever something is touched, the sound should play but maybe it's not detecting the touch event properly.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this link  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nF-HYoTurc8 and somewhat changed my code and the sound worked :D

In my PreviewTouchDown method, I added:

```
SoundPlayer soundPlayerAction = new SoundPlayer(TangramsTool.Properties.Resources.Selection);
soundPlayerAction.Play();
```